# Accessing Rails child objects within Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm very new to rails, so please bear with me.  I haven't quite grasped all the "magic" just yet.

Basically I need to access Location objects in Javascript, which all contain 0-N Coordinates.  I'm pretty sure the model is set up right, with each Coordinate having a location_id.

I managed to get a parsed JSON of Location objects using the following method:  I put

```
  def index
     @locations = Location.all.to_json
  end
```

in the controller, and accessed this in the view with

```
var theLocations = <%= @locations.html_safe %>;
```

when I show this variable in the log, however, it doesn't show the Coordinates, which kind of makes sense.  Thing is, I was planning to iterate over all the Locations and for each one create a javascript var with the relevant coordinates.  These vars would then be passed to Google maps as objects.

Basically I was planning on doing something like (pseudocode):

```
for(Location l in Locations){

    get all Coordinate objects within Location

    for(Coordinate c: Coordinates);

        var myObject = new google.maps.LatLng(c.X, c.Y),
        add myObject to list for this location.
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to approach this.  How can I get a reference to the Coordinates within the Locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is to pass a parameter in your `to_json` call:

```
@locations = Location.all.to_json(:include => :coordinate)
```

You may also want to [consider creating a custom JSON structure](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/) by overriding `as_json` and rendering the objects as JSON after that.

Comment: Worked a charm.  Thanks a lot.